# PHP Class error: Object of class indexPageClass could not be converted to string. How to solve this kind of issue?

Tags: php, class, oop

When I try to run the code the browser shows this error message:

```
Object of class indexPageClass could not be converted to string
```

This is the code that try to create the object:

```
$res = new indexPageClass();
echo $res;
```

This is the class indexPageClass:

```
class indexPageClass {
public function _construct() {

              $TopBar= $this->Header_TopBar_Content_lsti_();

return $TopBar;
 } 
private function Header_TopBar_Content_lsti_() {
$str=<<<EOF
<ul>
<li>
    <i class="fa fa-globe"></i>
    <a>Languages</a>
    <ul class="lenguages">
        <li class="active">
            <a href="#">English <i class="fa fa-check"></i></a> 
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Spanish</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="topbar-devider"></li>                       
<li><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#responsive">Login</a></li>  
</ul>
EOF;
return $str;  
 } 
}
```

I dont know what is going wrong.

Comment: You're echoing an object. Why do you do this?

Comment: your constructor needs two preceding underscores. `__construct()` not `_construct()`. You cannot really accomplish what you are trying to do using the constructor though, but the `__invoke()` method can do what you are looking for, see the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the entire object printed: `var_dump($res);`

If you want the entire object printed into a variable: `print_r($res, 1);`

If you want the object to return a string:

You can use the invoke magic method.
In your class add

```
function __invoke() {
    //put the stuff from your constructor in here
    return "your expected response";
}
```

and then where you are referencing the class:

```
$res = new indexPageClass();
echo $res();
```

Answer (score 1):

As I see you think that the returned value of a `__construct` is some kind of string, a result of calling a function.

But **it's not**.

Call for `new ClassName` returns object of `ClassName` class.
You should explicitly call some function to get an html string.
Or use `__toString` magic method.

Comment: with the current code, he could do `$res = new indexPageClass();
echo $res->__construct();` ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your class needs a `__toString()` function to tell it what to use in a string context.

http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/6/14/5

Answer (score 0):

add to class next code

```
public function __toString() {
  return $this->Header_TopBar_Content_lsti_();
}
```

is that what you want?

PS like

```
class indexPageClass {
public function _construct() {

              $TopBar= $this->Header_TopBar_Content_lsti_();

return $TopBar;
 } 
private function Header_TopBar_Content_lsti_() {
$str=<<<EOF
<ul>
<li>
    <i class="fa fa-globe"></i>
    <a>Languages</a>
    <ul class="lenguages">
        <li class="active">
            <a href="#">English <i class="fa fa-check"></i></a> 
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Spanish</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="topbar-devider"></li>                       
<li><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#responsive">Login</a></li>  
</ul>
EOF;
return $str;  
 } 

    public function __toString() {
      return $this->Header_TopBar_Content_lsti_();
    }
}
```